# Node JS - Custom command to run app.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

I want to be able to install my package through npm and then run `app.js` with a custom command without using `npm start`. I have looked around the web and many examples show adding a line in `scripts` in the `package.json` file, but all of these require it to be run using `npm start`. Is there a way to execute a `.js` file with node using a custom command e.g. `importer --file`?

Comment: You could always run node app.js

Comment: What do you mean by custom command?

Comment: I want to publish the package so it can be used from the command line e.g. by using `importer -file`

Comment: Does your `package.json` have the correct `bin` entry, as described [here in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin)? I believe if you install the package globally this executable name automatically gets added to the same directory where `npm` and `npx` are (they are done using this same method), and that directory should be in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before publishing your package, you'll need to have a `package.json` file with at least the following:

`{
  "name": "importer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "bin": "./importer.js"
}`